# TikzFooter and page numbering

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have an issue with Tikzfooter which I have not had before.  When I compile the tex file  the Tikzfooter (a Orange coloured node with page number does not appear on my document but no error message.  Tex files where it used to work is no longer working,  I suspect it may be when I updated.  One of the IT guys that I work with is having the same problem.

**The Script for the my working file**

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{book}

\input{board-formats}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tcol}{Orange!90}
\newcommand{\orr}{Orange!50!Red!90}

\newcommand{\runhead}{Document ---- 8 December 2013}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Header and footer stuff for First page
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\includepdf[scale=0.95]{Cover.pdf}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Contents Page
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{1.75em}
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.75em}
\makeatother

 \fontsize{10}{7pt}\usefont{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n} 

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}\pagenumbering{gobble}

\tableofcontents

\newpage



\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

 \normalsize

\fancyhead[E]{\tikzheade{\thechapter}}
\fancyhead[O]{\tikzhead{\thechapter}}
\fancyfoot{\tikzfoot{\thepage\ / \pageref{LastPage}}} 

% \mainmatter

\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Agenda}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\includepdf[scale=0.8, frame, angle=0, pages=1, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{Agenda.pdf}



\end{document}
```

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:

**The script of the format file is (Board-Formats-tex **

```
\usepackage{booktabs, tikz, pgf, longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem, longtable, caption, lscape}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{colortbl, hhline, comment}
 \usepackage{pifont}
% \usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}




\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10}{13pt}\usefont{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}}
\newcommand{\stabsize}{\fontsize{8}{12pt}\usefont{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{\arabic{enumi}.}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}~}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}

\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}

\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\theenumiii}

\newenvironment{zenumerate}
{
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=2mm, leftmargin=*]
}
{
\end{enumerate}
}



\newenvironment{zzenumerate}
{
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, itemsep=1mm]
}
{
\end{enumerate}
}

\newenvironment{zzzenumerate}
{
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, itemsep=0mm]
}
{
\end{enumerate}
}


\captionsetup{margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf, skip=4pt}

% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% %%%%%%%%% Symbols %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% \usepackage{amsfonts}


\newenvironment{zitem}
{
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=0cm]
}
{
\end{itemize}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\zrow}{\rowcolor{Orange!30}}




\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
% \thispagestyle{empty}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter.\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-1cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=\tcol, draw=\tcol] (0,0) rectangle
          (1.1*\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=west,
        xshift=1cm,
        rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=\orr]
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }


\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{cmr}


\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontsize{20}{30pt}\usefont{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}}
  {\thesection}{1em}{#1}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\fontsize{14}{16pt}\usefont{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}}
  {\thesubsection}{1em}{\textbf{#1}}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\fontsize{12}{12pt}\usefont{OT1}{cmss}{b}{n}}
  {\emph{\thesubsubsection}}{1em}{\emph{#1}}


\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{15pt}{-80pt}

\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{1.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection} {0pt}{1.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph} {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph} {\parindent}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}





\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\newcommand{\doj}{DoJ\&CD}

\setlength{\paperheight}{297mm}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{210mm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-10mm}
%\setlength{\topmargin}{9mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{240mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{160mm}
%\setlength{\headheight}{15.5mm}
%\setlength{\headsep}{23mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{10.6mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}  

\renewcommand\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
  \usefont{OT1}{cmss}{b}{n} {\bf #1}}



\newcommand*\tikzhead[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-0.5cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=\tcol, draw=\tcol, rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle
          (21.6cm,2cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.95\paperwidth,circle,
              rounded corners=15pt,inner sep=5pt,
              fill=\orr]
              {\color{black}\Large\textbf{#1}};
        \node[anchor=west, xshift=0.58cm,  rectangle,
              inner sep=3pt, rounded corners,
              fill=\orr]
              {\color{black} \runhead};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}}


\newcommand*\tikzheade[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-0.5cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=\tcol, draw=\tcol, rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle
          (21.6cm,2cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.1\paperwidth,circle,
              rounded corners=15pt,inner sep=5pt,
              fill=\orr]
              {\color{black}\Large#1};
        \node[anchor=east, xshift=20.3cm,  rectangle,
              inner sep=3pt, rounded corners,
              fill=\orr]
              {\color{black} \runhead};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand*\tikzfoot[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=0cm] at (current page.south west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=\tcol, draw=\tcol, rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle
          (21.6cm, 0.67cm);
        \node[xshift=10.8cm, yshift=0.3cm, 
              fill=\orr]
              {\color{black}\Large\textbf{#1}};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\zcomment}[1] { 
\vspace{3mm}
\setlength\fboxrule{2pt}
  % \colorbox{}{
  \fcolorbox{Orange}{orange!6!white}{
    \begin{minipage}[!h]{0.95\linewidth}
      \color{black}{

        \fontsize{10}{12pt}\usefont{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n} #1 }
    \end{minipage}
  }
  % }
  \setlength\fboxrule{0.7pt} 
\vspace{3mm}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\newcommand{\lfont}{\fontsize{10}{12pt}\usefont{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}}



%%%%%% Adding in pdf pages without page break


\newcommand{\inpdf}[2]{
  \includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\chapter{#2},\thispagestyle{fancy}},
  scale=0.8, frame]{#1}

  \includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}, scale=0.85, frame]{#1}
}



%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "Board-Report-Template"
%%% End:
```

Comment: Can you please add a complete document? Where is `\tikzfoot` defined?

Comment: Where did you find `\tikzfoot` command?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I suspect \tikzfoot is/was defined somewhere in your code and is used to produce a colored, filled or partially transparent node.  You don't actually need it.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I will post the script tomorrow.  The Tikzfooter is a colored node on the bottom of the page with a page number that no longer works. One of the It guys is experiencing the same problem. Documents where it used to work when we recompile them the Tikzfooter with page number disappears

Comment: Here is my code for my Tex File

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You have to compile the document atleast 2-3 times when `remember picture,overlay` is used with `tikzpicture`. Did you? I am getting the page number properly.

Comment: I have compiled this document 3 times and still the footer does not show with the page number.  I am using MikTex2.9 with TexStudio as the editor.  Am I using the right software?

Comment: I now merged your two questions to one. Please edit existing questions to add new content instead of posting it a second time.

Comment: Could you please reduce your code to the *minimum* necessary to reproduce the problem, ideally in the form of a single file?

Comment: Nested TiKZ pictures are often problematic. I can't imagine that nesting them when they have `remember picture, overlay` is likely to improve matters. I've tried minimising your code but, without any idea what you are trying to do, it is hard to be of much help.

Answer (score 2):

This should provide a start. I removed a bunch of stuff just to figure out what was going on. I've cleaned up the header/footer/layout dimensions and some of the TikZ code.

Note that there are small letters in some of the nodes so that you can more easily trace which bits of code do what. Obviously, these should be deleted.

A lot of it is guesswork, of course, since it is very unclear what you want to do. Fine-tuning is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{book}
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\gdef\chapterlabel{}
  \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries}
{\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter.\ }}{0pt}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[fill=tcol, draw=tcol] (current page.north west) ++(0,-10mm) coordinate (d) rectangle ++(1.1*\paperwidth,3cm);
    \node[anchor=west, xshift=1cm, rectangle, rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt, fill=orr, text=white] at (d) {\chapterlabel#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[textwidth=160mm, textheight=240mm, footskip=10.6mm, hmarginratio=1:1, marginparwidth=0pt, marginparsep=0pt, verbose]{geometry}% add showframe to see the layout

\tikzset{
  my draw/.style={fill=tcol, draw=tcol, rounded corners},
  my node/.style={fill=orr, text=black},
  my rectangle/.style={my node, rectangle},
}

\newcommand*\tikzhead[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[my draw] (current page.north west) ++(0,-5mm) coordinate (c) rectangle ++(21.6cm,2cm);
    \node[my node,xshift=.95\paperwidth,circle, anchor=east, rounded corners=15pt,inner sep=5pt, font=\Large\bfseries] at (c) {#1};
    \node[my rectangle, anchor=west, xshift=0.58cm, inner sep=3pt, rounded corners] at (c)  {a \runhead};
  \end{tikzpicture}}


\newcommand*\tikzheade[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[my draw] (current page.north west) ++(0,-5mm) coordinate (a)  rectangle ++(21.6cm,2cm);
    \node[my node,xshift=.1\paperwidth,anchor=east,circle, font=\Large] at (a) {#1};
    \node[xshift=20.3cm, anchor=east, my rectangle, inner sep=3pt, rounded corners] at (a) {b \runhead};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand*\tikzfoot[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw [my draw] (current page.south west) coordinate (b)  rectangle ++(21.6cm, 0.67cm);
    \node [xshift=10.8cm, yshift=0.3cm, my node, font=\Large\bfseries] at (b)  {c #1};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[E]{\tikzheade{\thechapter}}
\fancyhead[O]{\tikzhead{\thechapter}}
\fancyfoot{\tikzfoot{\thepage\ / \pageref{LastPage}}}
\newcommand{\runhead}{Document ---- 8 December 2013}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% probably you want this? though it is hard to tell...
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}%
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}%
}

\colorlet{tcol}{Orange!80}
\colorlet{orr}{Orange!50!Red!80}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

  \begin{titlepage}
    Some title
  \end{titlepage}


  \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
  \pagenumbering{roman}
  \tableofcontents

  \clearpage
  \pagenumbering{arabic}

  \chapter{Agenda}
  \thispagestyle{fancy}
  \includepdf[scale=0.8, frame, angle=0, pages=1, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{example-image-letter}

  \kant[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: headers and footers]